# Override highlight group settings with default values

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

I am writing a plugin that highlights buffer settings violations.

I use `matchadd()` function. In addition I need to add patterns that are force ignored. In order to achieve that I use priorities in `matchadd()`.

I use the following highlight group to highlight trailing spaces:

```
highligh FileStyleTrailngSpacesError ctermbg=Cyan guibg=Cyan
```

Matching trailing spaces code:

```
matchadd('FileStyleTrailngSpacesError', '\s\+$', 1)
```

Force highlight disabling supposed to be (e.g. pattern `>\s\+$`):

```
matchadd('Normal', '>\s\+$', 1)
```

The problem is that this line of code does not disable highlight, but it "works" with other highlight groups e.g. `Todo`

I also tried to use the following groups:

```
" Has the same result as 'Normal'
highligh FileStyleIgnorePattern cterm=NONE guibg=NONE

" E420: BG color unknown
highligh FileStyleIgnorePattern ctermbg=bg guibg=bg
```

**UPDATE:** OS - Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Beware that there's a (small but non-zero) runtime price to each `matchadd()`.  Perhaps a better approach might be to keep a list of IDs and delete the relevant ones rather than make them do nothing.

Comment: @lcd047 I would like to do it this way, but the issue is that pattern, that should be ignored actually have a subpattern that should be highlighted in all other places except matching ignored one (e.g. `\s\+$` and `>\s\+\$` that should be ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `guibg=NONE`, you actually say "this has *no* background color", i.e. it is transparent. The `bg` value is the right approach, but that only works for `guibg`; for `ctermbg`, you indeed get the `E420` error (from the `:help E420`: *This only works after setting the colors for the Normal group and for the MS-DOS console.*) . So, you need to specify
the actual background color for color terminals:

```
highlight FileStyleIgnorePattern ctermbg=White guibg=bg
```

You could use `synIDattr()` to query the color terminal background color, but I guess that will only work if a color has been set explicitly, too.

Comment: Well, you a right about `synIDattr()`. I tried the following example: `:echo synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."), col("."), 1)), "bg")`.
It returns nothing on regular text.